# Multiple selection in an iOS picker view

Tags: forms, tables, ios, selection

The iOS SDK doesn't have a multiple selection picker view. However Safari's picker view allows multiple selection. Fortunately [ALPickerView](https://github.com/alexleutgoeb/ALPickerView) was created to allow multiple selection in a picker view. Is there any good reason to not use a multiple selection picker since Apple didn't put it in the SDK?

The context I'm using it in is a long table view form. All the other entry elements popup a keyboard or picker on selection with next/previous buttons like Safari. I would think that it would ruin the flow of filling out the form if I pushed another table view on the user in the middle of filling out the form.

Answer (score 2):

The single picker view is well entrenched among iOS users by now, so you would need to find a way of letting your users know that it is a multiple selector.  Right now, the project example page **looks just like a single selector**, which would lead me to believe that it was a single selector.

If you show me a doorknob, I will assume that it turns.  If you show me a new doorknob I need to press to open, I will still try to turn it.

Find a way to **make it obvious** to your customers, or train them.  But most of all, test whether it is improving your design or confusing your customers.

---

This answer hasn't touched on the question of whether Apple will allow an app with a multiple picker.  If they aren't going to allow it, you will have no choice but not to use it.  Find this out first.